# Android Studio fails to draw layout from XML

Tags: android-studio, layout, rendering

This is the layout in xml, which is unable to generate the layout view in Android Studio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:elevation="7dp"
        android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="20dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                app:title="something ">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_layout_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appBarLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="something"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/front_page_title_text_size" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_view_see_more"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:text="something"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/front_page_title_text_size" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="something"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/front_page_title_text_size" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="something "
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/front_page_title_text_size" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

having following errors:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7200)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl.java:1925)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl_Accessor.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl_Accessor.java:24)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.requestFitSystemWindows(Layout.java:385)
    at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
    at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
    at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
    at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
    at android.view.View.requestApplyInsets(View.java:10804)
    at androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(ViewCompat.java:2426)
    at androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$Api21Impl$1.onApplyWindowInsets(ViewCompat.java:4774)
    at android.view.View.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(View.java:10514)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7191)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl.java:1925)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl_Accessor.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl_Accessor.java:24)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.requestFitSystemWindows(Layout.java:385)
    at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
    at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
    at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
    at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
    at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
    at android.view.View.requestApplyInsets(View.java:10804)
    at androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(ViewCompat.java:2426)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout.onAttachedToWindow(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:264)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:19575)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3430)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:335)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:373)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:713)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:844)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I have the same issue and it started with updating the Android studio and the supporting libraries

Comment: i think i had got it working downgrading the android gradle plugin